# 'appium' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, command-prompt, appium

Trying to install appium on Windows using the following command:
`npm install -g appium`

But I am getting following error.Please give me some solutions to solve this problem.Just i downloaded appium for windows then I tried `npm install -g appium` command in command prompt.

```
    C:\Users\Gideon>npm install -g appium
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git://githu
b.com/vojtajina/traceur-compiler) undefined
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git://githu
b.com/vojtajina/traceur-compiler) undefined
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/vojtajina/traceur-compiler undefined
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/vojtajina/traceur-compiler undefined
\


> bufferutil@1.0.1 install C:\Users\Gideon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appi
um\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

|
C:\Users\Gideon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\ws\node_mod
ules\bufferutil>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\
\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:108:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
 ERR! cwd C:\Users\Gideon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\w
s\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.0.1


> utf-8-validate@1.0.1 install C:\Users\Gideon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
appium\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Gideon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\ws\node_mod
ules\utf-8-validate>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-
bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:108:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Gideon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_module
s\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.0.1
-


> ws@0.5.0 install C:\Users\Gideon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_
modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

|
C:\Users\Gideon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\socket.io\n
ode_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
|
> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\Gideon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node
_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\n
ode_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Users\Gideon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\socket.io\n
ode_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws>node
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\n
ode-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35
","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.1
0.35","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35"
,"npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35"
,"npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35"
,"npm":"1.4.28"})
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "appium"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Gideon
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! not ok code 0


C:\Users\Gideon>appium
```

> 'appium' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: What do you mean by you downloaded appium for windows then i tries npm install -g appium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for valuable inputs!

I am adding further solution.

While installing

`npm install -g appium`

by default system variable is set to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` and this gives you error:

> 'appium' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

To resolve above error you need to give system variable is `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, so remove `\` if you are using OS Windows10, otherwise give semicolon end of the syntax, like as follow: `C:\Program Files\nodejs;`

Hope this solved the problem!

Answer (score 13):

Even I struggled for a day, it finally worked.

`NPM`, by default will get installed in `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

But other required node modules will get installed in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm`

The System Environment's `PATH` variable will be set to `C:\Program Files\nodejs` and **not** in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm`, so kindly add this directory to the `PATH` variable.

[image: Setting another directory]

Then copy the appium folder which is downloaded
**From:** `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`
**To:** `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`

Then the command `appium --version` should work globally.

Tested twice, working for me, hope it helps everyone.

Regards,
Vineeth

Answer (score 1):

If you install appium through command  `npm install -g appium` and showing error

```
'appium' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Add a new value to path variable in environment variable(Control panel-> advanced settings)

```
C:\Users\YourUsername....\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\.bin\
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need to check your system's `PATH` variable.

`Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> select PATH -> Edit ->`

Mine has:

> C:\Ruby193\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\wbin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SimpleIDE\propeller-gcc\bin;c:\python27;c:\python27\scripts;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd

Note that I had to manually add the one for `Ruby`, `Python` and `python\scripts`, `Nodejs`, `Git\cmd`, `...`

You might need to do that to and then reboot to put those into place.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try these steps after installing **Node.js**:

**1)** Click on the `Start` button
**2)** Search `Node.js command prompt` and open it
**3)** Type command `npm install -g appium` (and it will start installing)
**5)** Further more, close all the Windows `cmd` and start a new one
**6)** Search `appium -v` to check if it's installed.

Then you won't face the problem. I have struggled for a day, then after following these steps it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have given answer here for nodemon. But the same will for appium too. To fix the issue follow from step 2 - [Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53711051/9791932)