# The term 'nodemon' is not recognized

Tags: node.js, nodemon

nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

just trying to install nodemon globally but it is not recognizing.....
( node install nodemon-g )in terminal.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuJqg.png)

Comment: Try `sudo npm install -g nodemon` :D

Comment: i'm using windows vscode :D

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

If the below steps do not work for you, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359590/nodemon-command-is-not-recognized-in-terminal-for-node-js-server/53711051#53711051) as nodemon might not be added to the PATH after installation.

---

Nodemon is a **Node Package** that is managed by the **Node Package Manager (NPM)**.

To install Node Packages, you need to use the following command,

```
npm i package-name    // This will install the package locally as a dependency
npm i -D package-name // This will install the package locally as a dev dependency
npm i -g package-name // This will install the package globally
```

And so, to install nodemon globally, you would do,

```
npm i -g nodemon      // For Windows or if you installed NodeJS using NVM on linux
sudo npm i -g nodemon // If you installed NodeJS from from apt or other linux package manager.
```

`node install whatever` is not a command and obviously won't work.

Comment: @Vickygrk If the answer worked for you, do accept it. If you are still having the issue, do let us know.

Comment: Yes , i have an issue  ------- First i install (npm i nodemon -g) globally, after installed nodmon globally i use this command (nodemon app.js) it says //nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon app.js
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException//

Comment: @Vickygrk Try this answer as I think it is an issue with nodemon not being recognized in the path, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53711051/12135751

Comment: You should do `npm i nodemon --save-dev`, then to run it, `node_modules\.bin\nodemon`. Then this project will have its own special nodemon, and you won't have a version war on your machine when you have more than one codebase. You can also control the version of the nodemon this project uses, in case you need, by adding the version to the install command or editing `package,json`.