# Nodemon is Not Working : [nodemon] Not Working

Tags: node.js, nodemon

```
nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon ap.js
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Can we have details on how you get this error ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodemon command is not recognized in terminal for node js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359590/nodemon-command-is-not-recognized-in-terminal-for-node-js-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install nodemon as a global package

`npm install -g nodemon`

Comment: try this open terminal in your project and type this **npm install --save-dev nodemon** and if this doesn't work then try to reinstall node js in your system