# Unsure why nodemon isn't working, tried all solutions

Tags: npm, npm-install, nodemon

I've installed nodemon globally many times but when I try and run it, it doesn't work. This is the error I'm getting:

```
nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.    
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon server.js
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandN  
   otFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I don't understand why I can't use nodemon when I've installed it globally. I get this error in my VSCode terminal but in my cmd.exe, I get this error:

```
'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried installing it globally from both the terminal and command prompt. I've also tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, and reinstalling them by doing `npm install`. I don't understand why this is happening and don't know what to do.

Comment: seems that your path might be messed up.. Try `C:\>npm config get prefix` - copy the output and paste it as new environmental var inside your advanced settings (when on WIN).. then run it and see ifit works..

Comment: Do I do it as a system variable or User variable? EDIT: I did it and it's still not working

Comment: As you like - do you want it system-wide or for a specific user? -> pls see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359590/nodemon-command-is-not-recognized-in-terminal-for-node-js-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `npx nodemon`, your environment variables of your OS are probably broken and don't link to where npm global packages get installed.

Comment: How can I fix my environmental variable? In the "User variables" portion I added a new "path" variable and linked it to the output of `npm config get prefix` of my machine. I also added that output to the path in my system variables. Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10

Answer (score 0):

your npm that module does not support or is not compatible with Nodemon so
try to use

> npx

instead of

> `npm`

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly under RHEL8.9 and NodeJS v12.22.0, I use npm to start my client and server instances. There is an operator for npm called stop but it fails in a missing script error each time. Based on your blog here, npx does work normally with npx stop server, for one example. However, nodemon is still resident in memory and ports are still being enabled for nodeman.